# React Grommet Select - passing in object data as options

Tags: reactjs, grommet

I am using Grommet v2 components and trying to mirror the display used in the Select 'Seasons' example in Grommet's storybook.

The field appears like this: 
[image]

The difference is my data needs to separate label and value:

```
const Options = [
   {
     label: "S01",
     value: "283736"
   },
   {
     label: "S02",
     value: "293774"
   },
```

instead of using the default:

```
const Options = [
  "S01",
  "S02",
```

Here is an example on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmvz66vyx0)

The object format was used in Grommet's example of ObjectMultiSelect in their [storybook](https://storybook.grommet.io/?path=/story/select--object-multiple). I found the Select component needs 
`labelKey="label"` and `valueKey="value"` to load the objects as options, but adding these two props seems to break the component options.

I would like for the data passed in to resemble

```
const Options = [
   {
     label: "S01",
     value: "283736"
   },
   {
     label: "S02",
     value: "293774"
   },
```

and still have the options displayed as above.

Comment: Grommet has labeled this as an enhancement: https://github.com/grommet/grommet/issues/3061

Answer (score 1):

```
            <Select
              options={[
                {
                  lab: "S01",
                  val: "283736"
                },
                {
                  lab: "S02",
                  value: "293774"
                }
              ]}
              labelKey="lab"
              dropHeight="large"
              name="primaryServer"
              value={this.props.values.primaryServer}
              placeholder="Select Primary Server"
              emptySearchMessage={"No Servers Available"}
              onChange={({ option }) => {
                console.log(option.lab)
                console.log(option.val)
              }}
            />
            // Output // S01 // 283736
            // This worked for me. labelKey="lab" is required.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.